# Create UIView programmatically with Objective-C to work in both portrait and landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I've to create a view in objective c with two labels on it, label1 has single line and label2 is multi line based on content.

**Based on content in the labels I want to adjust view height how can I do that?**

Width of the view should be 20 left and right to screen width with below code I can show in portrait but in landscape it was not coming properly, **It crops on the right side. How can I do show that right 20 for landscape?**

Portrait

[image]

Landscape

[image]

```
    UIView *emptyTreeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,self.view.frame.size.width - 40,400)];
    UILabel *label1 =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0, 30.0, self.view.frame.size.width - 100, 30.0)];
    UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0, 90.0, self.view.frame.size.width - 100, 100.0)];
    emptyTreeView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    label1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label1.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
    label1.numberOfLines = 0;
    label1.text = @"The Page Cannot be displayed.";
    label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label2.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    label2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    label2.numberOfLines = 0;
    label2.text = @"Please use this feature or contact your internal contact person directly.";
    [emptyTreeView addSubview:label1];
    [emptyTreeView addSubview:label2];
    [self.view addSubview:emptyTreeView];
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @Rob I've updated my question with your suggested changes it was not working as expected can you check once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few observations:

1. Do not add subviews in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. That is only for adjusting `frame` values.
2. If you refer to `self.view`, reference its `bounds`, not its `frame`. The former is for coordinates of subviews within `self.view`. The latter is in the coordinate system of its superview (which might not introduce any differences right now, but is just the wrong coordinate system.
3. If you want the view to resize on rotation, set its `autoresizingMask`, e.g.

   ```
   emptyTreeView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
   ```

   Or

   ```
   emptyTreeView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
   ```
4. Nowadays, setting frame values and autoresizing masks is a bit of an anachronism. We would generally use constraints, e.g.

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       UIView *emptyTreeView = [[UIView alloc] init];
       UILabel *label1 =  [[UILabel alloc] init];
       UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
       emptyTreeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
       label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
       label1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
       label1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
       label1.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
       label1.numberOfLines = 0;
       label1.text = @"The Page Cannot be displayed.";
       label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
       label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
       label2.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
       label2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
       label2.numberOfLines = 0;
       label2.text = @"Please use this feature or contact your internal contact person directly.";
       [emptyTreeView addSubview:label1];
       [emptyTreeView addSubview:label2];
       [self.view addSubview:emptyTreeView];

       emptyTreeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
       label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
       label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

       [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
           [emptyTreeView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor constant:20],
           [emptyTreeView.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor constant:-10],
           [emptyTreeView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor constant:20],

           [label1.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:emptyTreeView.leftAnchor constant:20],
           [label1.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:emptyTreeView.rightAnchor constant:-20],
           [label1.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:emptyTreeView.topAnchor constant:20],

           [label2.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:emptyTreeView.leftAnchor constant:20],
           [label2.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:emptyTreeView.rightAnchor constant:-20],
           [label2.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:label1.bottomAnchor constant:20],

           [emptyTreeView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:label2.bottomAnchor constant:20]
       ]];
   }
   ```

   Note the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is `false` and the constraints.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked as expected.